# ayuda con expresion regular PHP

Tags: php, regex, text

tengo el siguiente código:

```
$tiempo=  shell_exec(" curl -o /dev/null -w 'Conexión: %{time_connect} FB: % {time_starttransfer} Tiempo Total: %{time_total} \n' " . $dominio);
echo "<br>";
    echo "Tiempos de carga: ". $tiempo;
    $conexion=;
    $FB=;
    $TTotal=;
```

Pero me falta una expresión regular que meta cada numero de la variable `$tiempo` en cada variable, el lo saca con el siguiente formato:

> Conexión: 0.000 FB: 0.000 Tiempo Total: 0.060

Y estoy intentando con algo parecido a una expresión regular como esta:

```
\FB: [0-9]
```

Pero no me funciona correctamente, si alguien me puede echar una mano.
Gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te sugeriria [leer un poco mas acerca de como funcionan las expresiones regulares](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expression-language-quick-reference), como por ejemplo [el cuantificadores](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expression-language-quick-reference#quantifiers) `+` que te permite hacer coincidencia con mas de un caracter del mismo tipo.

Esto deberia poder funcionarte:

```
<?php

$texto = "Conexión: 0.000 FB: 0.000 Tiempo Total: 0.060";

preg_match("/Conexión:\s(\d+\.\d+)/", $texto, $matches_time_connect);
$time_connect = $matches_time_connect[1];

echo "Primer Match: " . $matches_time_connect[0] . " | Valor: " . $time_connect . "<br/>";


preg_match("/FB:\s(\d+\.\d+)/", $texto, $matches_time_starttransfer);
$time_starttransfer = $matches_time_starttransfer[1];

echo "Segundo Match: " . $matches_time_starttransfer[0] . " | Valor: " . $time_starttransfer . "<br/>";


preg_match("/Total:\s(\d+\.\d+)/", $texto, $matches_time_total);
$time_total = $matches_time_total[1];

echo "Tercer Match: " . $matches_time_total[0] . " | Valor: " . $time_total . "<br/>";

?>
```

Esto responde con

> Primer Match: Conexión: 0.000 | Valor: 0.000
>
> Segundo Match: FB: 0.000 | Valor: 0.000
>
> Tercer Match: Total: 0.060 | Valor: 0.060

Comment: pues no me funciona de esa manera, he intentado algo parecido a esto pero tampoco me funciona.. alguna idea???
$conexion = preg_grep("/Conexión:\s(\d+\.\d+)/", $tiempo);
echo "conexion: ". $conexion;

Comment: Veo que has aceptado la respuesta. Te ha funcionado?

Comment: No, de esta forma no me ha funcionado, y tampoco con la que he intentado (en el comentario)
alguna otra sugerencia????
le Di el OK como agradecimiento, pero realmente no me ha funcionado 
Gracias

Comment: Cual es el resultado de cuando llamas al `preg_match`? Te da algun error?

Comment: no me devuelve nada, NULL

Comment: He actualizado la respuesta con un ejemplo totalmente funcional, pero me parece extraño que no te funcione. He corrido el ejemplo tal cual en [phpfiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/) y he obtenido resultados. Podrias probar con esta version que he colocado?